# Upgrading Sonarqube from 4.5 to 4.5.1 won't work

Tags: jruby, sonarqube

I'm trying to updgrade Sonarqube from 4.5 to 4.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. The package manager serves the new version and it installed apparently without any problem. However, when I try to access the web UI it takes me to the page where it says I need to upgrade the database. So I go to the **my_sonar_server/setup** page and click upgrade. After few seconds, the following message appears

> Exclamation Impossible to upgrade database
>
> Migration failed: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: no connection available: alter table snapshot_sources modify data longtext .
>   Please check logs.

The sonar.log has the following exception

> 2014.11.10 10:04:38 INFO  web[DbMigration]  MysqlMediumtextToLongtext: migrating
>
> 2014.11.10 10:04:42 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: no connection available: alter
>   table snapshot_sources modify data longtext
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in
>   `log'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in`
>   execute'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/db/migrate/600_mysql_mediumtext_to_longtext.rb:42:in
>   `apply'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/db/migrate/600_mysql_mediumtext_to_longtext.rb:30:in`
>   up'
>           org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in`
>   migrate'
>           jar:file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in
>   `measure'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in`
>   migrate'
>           org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in`
>   migrate'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in
>   `migrate'
>           org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in`call'
>           org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in`
>   ddl_transaction'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in
>   `migrate'
>           org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in
>   `migrate'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in`
>   up'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in
>   `migrate'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in`upgrade_and_start'
>           /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:109:in
>   `start_migration'
>           org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in`call'
>           org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that one of tables (`snapshot_sources`) got corrupted at some point, presumably when we cloned our production server to have a test server.

When I tried to access a particular row on that particular table either through phpmyadmin or the command line, the database connection was lost (`mysqld` process was restarting itself). I investigated the root of the problem (by digging `/var/log/mysql/error.log`) along with our IT team, and reached the aforementioned conclusion.

So, the migration of the database was being interrupted because of this, due to the fact that the migration was trying to alter `snapshot_sources` table to convert the `data` field from `mediumtext` to `longtext`

The way I fixed it was:

1. Export the production DB (with `truncate` sentences to empty the tables before importing)
2. Backup the corrupted DB for further investigation if required
3. Import the production DB onto the test server
4. Upgrade SQ from 4.5 to 4.5.1

Hope this helps someone else or at least it is a sort of heads up for Sonar team.

Comment: Thank you! I simply truncated that one table, and the upgrade was able to continue. After the next analysis, I will have data again in that table. The data loss is acceptable in our case.

Answer (score -1):

The log is explicit enough: `ConnectionNotEstablished`. This means that you haven't configured your SonarQube instance correctly to access the database...

Comment: Exactly Fabrice, that's the high level problem. However, it wasn't as simple as that. I've figured out what the problem was after 8h+ of investigation. See the answer to my question